# multiple local yum repositories possible?

Tags: yum, repository

I am working with offline boxes.
There are different versions of a software which just work with certin patch levels of CentOS.

My idea is/was to create an image with local repositories.
I intended a basic local repository for CentOS only and small repositories for the different software patch levels.

I wanted to have the basic repo online at all times and simply add remove repo entries of the software versions based on the needs.

Example. local.repo as static part in the image, software_version_A.repo and software_version_B.repo will be added manually in the post-installation. but only one of these 2.
The repositories themselves are all locate in /repo/...

Problem is that CentOS complains about the presence of more than one local repositories.
Is it possible to do it as I have planned at all?
If not, is there a way to organize the yum repo like e.g. svn and create branches or snapshots?

Comment: I assume it complains about the name "local" used twice, not about beeing local? Make sure your second `.repo` file is  named `local2` and the head is `[local2]` as well. You can add multiple repos, the only difference to local repos is the source `file:` instead of `https`

Comment: Install  yum-priorities : `# yum install yum-priorities` ... Example http://keihsler.com/redmine/projects/dw_os_cos7/wiki/Setup_yum-priorities

Comment: Finally I had the possibility to test your advice.
You're right. I had the same label "local" in different repo files X)

Thanks for yourhelp, mate :)